# Laravel 8 : Route [welcome] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to add a new blade before the login screen. The welcome.blade.

So I

- created the welcome.blade.php under views
- added the route in web.php :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');
```

- Updated the Authenticate.php middleware in order to redirect not logged in users to welcome:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('welcome');
        }
    }
```

But when I visit the url I get `local.ERROR: Route [welcome] not defined`

Also welcome is not in the list returned by `php artisan route:list`

I have trying clearing all cache but I still get this error.

Comment: run this command & check if you see welcome route in list

php artisan route:list

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain I did but its not there... strange

Comment: show me how you have defined login route

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain https://pastebin.com/jE3E99Cz

Comment: Change the route URL to `/welcome` and see if that works. If the route for landing page `/` is defined in routes it would overwrite yours.

Comment: run `php artisan route:cache` or `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache and try again!
If still show error run `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

php artisan optimize

Or
php artisan route:clear

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).